# Updating my jQuery broke my show/hide

Tags: jquery

I have a script that changes a phone number, but this script will only work with jquery 1.6.4 --  it ceased to function once I updated to 1.7.2.  What am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

$('a#reno-trigger').click(function(){
$('#toggle-lv').show();
$('#toggle-reno').hide();
});

$('a#lv-trigger').click(function(){
$('#toggle-reno').show();
$('#toggle-lv').hide();
});



// ]]></script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="toggle-reno"><div class="toggle-switch" >
<span class="active">Las Vegas</span> | <a id="reno-trigger" href="#">Reno</a></div>
<div class="toggle-phone">702.555.5555</div>
</div>

<div id="toggle-lv" style="display: none"><div class="toggle-switch" >
<a id="lv-trigger" href="#">Las Vegas</a> | <span class="active">Reno</span></div>
<div class="toggle-phone">555.555.5555</div>
</div>
```

I am going to remove this line and the script will no longer work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I took out the CDATA as well.

My wordpress is loading a local version of 1.7.2.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://xxx.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>
```

I've added:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And it works again, but I am loading two jQueries which seems strange.

I guess it isn't the update of jQuery after all...

The document.ready is implemented now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
$('a#reno-trigger').click(function(){
$('#toggle-lv').show();
$('#toggle-reno').hide();
});

$('a#lv-trigger').click(function(){
$('#toggle-reno').show();
$('#toggle-lv').hide();
});

);
</script>
```

That script didn't work period, I must have screwed up the document.ready part... I've put it back for now.

Comment: Any JavaScript errors? Any HTML we can look at?

Comment: Not sure why it depends on the version, but you should put this code inside the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that should have broken by updating to 1.7.2

Comment: Get rid of the `// <![CDATA[` `// ]]>` stuff.

Comment: You don't need both. Get rid of one.

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out, I was getting rid of the old 1.6.4 and it broke.  The one that my framework relies on isn't enough and I can't for the life of me figure out why :(

Comment: _"My wordpress is loading a local version of 1.7.2"_ - How sure are you that it is _actually_ loading? Have you checked your browser's console? The document ready version shown at the end of your question is incorrect: you have to pass it a function. Needs to be `$(document).ready(function(){ /*your code here*/ });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('a#reno-trigger').click(function(){
        $('#toggle-lv').show();
        $('#toggle-reno').hide();
    });

    $('a#lv-trigger').click(function(){
        $('#toggle-reno').show();
        $('#toggle-lv').hide();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: This worked, but only because I had to include a second jQuery.  (It also works with the original function.)

Comment: Make sure you're loading the jQuery `<script>` **before** loading any other `<script>` that is a dependent.

Comment: When viewing the page source, it appears to be in order.

Answer (score 0):

This works, I am not sure why.  But it works :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('a#reno-trigger').click(function(){
$('#toggle-lv').show();
$('#toggle-reno').hide();
});

$('a#lv-trigger').click(function(){
$('#toggle-reno').show();
$('#toggle-lv').hide();
});

 });



// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Isn't this identical to my answer?

Comment: The reason it works is because wrapping it in `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... });` (which can also be written as `$(function(){ ... });`) waits for the document to fully load (DOM to be ready) before executing the script.

Comment: I pasted in your solution and it doesn't work, but since you are the only one who posted an actual answer I can accept yours as it lead me on the right path.... well I combined yours with Barmar's suggestion and added my own touch! :P